# What will happen to thread B if thread A is killed in same process?

Tags: multithreading, kernel, kill

> Suppose a process spawns a thread A and this thread further spawns a new thread B, now suppose thread A is killed then what will happen to the thread B.

I think if these are KLTs then surely nothing will happen to thread B is killed. And for ULTs also nothing should happen to the thread B

Comment: Thread B wil keep on executing. Thread works in fire and forget way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. What happens during the forking process is that thread B starts by getting a reference to the thread A's page tables (virtual memory reference). As soon as there is any change to these page tables from either A or B, a copy is created (for each page) and given to both of them. In this case B will just inherit all of the page-tables and do its own thing.

Comment: Are you sure when a thread creates another thread fork() is used, and each and every thread has page tables associated with it?

Comment: Well you can either use fork or execv. The difference is in the way memory is allocated. In fork the page tables are inherited while in execv brand new memory is given to the process. And yes each and every thread has page tables associated with it.